# Performing FFT on a time-domain signal using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, frequency-analysis

I have been trying to perform signal processing action (FFT) on a time-domain signal, which I have obtained from another software. However, I keep getting a wrong answer (**figure 1**), when I use the following code. The sampling frequency of the signal is 1600.

```
%Healthy engine IAS
DATAH=xlsread('IASH_5seconds_1500rpm_FS1600.xlsx');

xh=DATAH(:,1);

yh=DATAH(:,2);

plot(xh,yh);

hold on;

legend('a','b')

%% performing fft

Fs=1600;

L=length(yh);

NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L);

X = fft(yh,NFFT)/L;

f = Fs*linspace(0,1,NFFT);

plot(f,2*abs(X))
```

I tried with Amesime software to get its frequency spectrum, and I did right (**see figure 2**). But, I want to do this with MATLAB.
I don't have any clue where my mistake is. My problem becomes odder for me when I just change the signal and the code works perfectly. So, I thought my signal has a problem. Does my signal have a problem (you can see the signal in **figure 3**)?

Figure 1:

[image: Figure 1]

Figure 2:

[image: Figure 2]

Figure 3:
[image: Figure 3]

Comment: A few thoughts, in no specific order: 1) Figure 3 seems to have a DC (0 Hz) component, as it's offset. Your Amesime result does not show this; 2) You're missing some kind of fftshift operation in your matlab code; 3) You say your sampling frequency is 1600Hz but don't account for this in your matlab code.

Comment: I suggest you don't use a blank line after each line of code. That only makes the code more difficult to read

Comment: @RPM 1) Indeed, and that's the main source of discrepancy as it drowns out everything else due to low-frequency spectral leakage and plot scaling. 2) Not really. Amesime is limiting the spectrum to the lower non-redundant half. OP could do the same. No `fftshift` required in that case. 3) Actually the OP does with the `f = Fs*linspace(0,1,NFFT);` line (although this includes the endpoint "1" which shouldn't be included)

Comment: In time domain it seems that your signal has a DC offset of approximately 1500. In your frequency diagram you can find this offset with a value of 3000. This seems to be fine because you multiplied X with 2. However, in diagram 2 the maximum amplitude is approximately 2.4. Maybe the flat line in diagram 1 isn't flat at all, but has values between 0 and 2.5, wich can't be visible with a DC value of 3000. Just remove the DC value in your diagram 1, so that all values in the diagram are of comparable amplitude.